# Where are my photos stored?

Tags: mac, photos

I am new to OS X. In my `About this Mac -> Storage`, I have 21GB of photos. However, I have checked the *Photos* application and there are nothing in it.

I am not sure where these photos are stored as I don't usually use this computer for storing photos. I guess they might have been imported when I plugged in my iPhone, somehow. What is the best way to track them down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Finder, under the File menu, select "Find" (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>). In the window that opens, leave the first pulldown menu at "Kind", go to the next pulldown and select "Image" then hit enter. Assuming you set the search to "This Mac," the Finder will then list every image file on your computer, allowing you to see exactly where they are.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to open search and type "Pictures".  The result you want to click on should be the second or third result.

Another method is to open Finder and navigate to the `Pictures` directory in your home folder.

Comment: Using Spotlight to search for "photos" yields the result you're going for, but (at least on my machine) it was buried way down in the list. You probably want to specify what the user should click on after searching, as the top result is the Photos app which the OP already stated is empty.